# Maven installation Fails

Tags: maven

I am  new to Maven. I am trying to run the below command after successfully configuring `JAVA_HOME`, `M2_HOME` and `M2 paths`.

```
    mvn -X mvn:install
```

and after downloading couple of things I get error at.

```
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at      10.3 KB/sec)
 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\jafar_000\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-    status.properties
 [DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local  (C:\Users\jafar_000\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\jafar_000\.m2\repository)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52.126 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-02T21:54:07+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'mvn' in the current project and in the plugin groups   [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.cod
the repositories [local (C:\Users\jafar_000\.m2\repository), central    (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'mvn' in the current project and
apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local   (C:\Users\jafar_000\.m2\repository), centra
e.org/maven2)]
        at     org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
        at     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycle
103)
    at        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(Defau    ltLifecycle
83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following  articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I am working on windows and Maven version 3.2.5

Comment: What are you trying to do? Who/what told you to execute `mvn -X mvn:install`? Does `mvn --version` work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `mvn install` as `install` is a lifecycle, not a plugin.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html for more info.

Comment: are you sure i need to run install. I have not created any project yet.

Comment: I am getting this error `[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the
 correct directory. -> [Help 1]`.

Comment: You need have a `pom.xml` file in your project to get started. The easiest way is to create one from an [archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html). You might want to read the getting started guide to get up to speed: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/